# How to connect to remote machine in Ruby with "raw" connection type like in PuTTY?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sockets, printing, putty

I want to communicate with remote printer which has IP "xxxxx" and port number "xxx". I am able to connect to printer through PuTTY and can issue the command to the printer and printer is executing those commands.

Below are the images that describes the steps that I am doing to connect to printer and issue the command to it.

[image]

As you can see in the above image I am using "raw" connection type.

[image]

Above image shows the command that I am issuing to printer after connecting it via "raw" connection type.

I want to connect to remote machine (printer) via Ruby programming language with "Raw" connection type as shown in the first image of PuTTY. But I am not able to do it. Also there are libraries for SSH and Telnet but there is no library that can connect to remote machine (printer) with "raw" connection type.

I want to know how can I connect to remote machine (printer) with "Raw" connection type like PuTTY and issue the command to the printer.

Thanks,
Sanjay Salunkhe

Answer (score 1):

Just use the plain [`TCPSocket` class](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/socket/rdoc/TCPSocket.html):

```
require 'socket'

s = TCPSocket.new '192.168.25.168', 20000

s.puts "MARK START" # send command
line = s.gets       # read response
puts line           # print it

s.puts "MARK STOP"
line = s.gets
puts line

s.close             # close socket when done
```